# How to target a dropdown selector using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show and hide divs when selecting an option from the dropdown selector.

Div 1 (season 1) should show on load, Div 2 (season 2) should be hidden.

When you select Div 2 (season 2) through the dropdown, Div 1 (season 1) should hide, div 2 (season 1) should show, and vise versa.

here's my HTML -

```
 <h4>Season:</h4> 
    <select>
      <option value="s1">Winter 2017</option>
      <option value="s2">Summer 2017</option>
  </select>
<div id="season1">
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>GP</th> 
    <th>G</th>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>Pnts</th>
    <th>PiM</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Adam</td>
    <td>12</td> 
    <td>2</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="season2">
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>GP</th> 
    <th>G</th>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>Pnts</th>
    <th>PiM</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Brad</td>
    <td>15</td> 
    <td>5</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $('#season1').show();
                $('#season2').hide();


                $('#s1').prop('selected', true(e) {
                    $('#season1').show();
                    $('#season2').hide();
                });

                $('#s2').prop('selected', true(e) {
                    $('#season1').hide();
                    $('#season2').show();
                });


            });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p40139bd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed `s1` and `s2` to `season1` and `season2`, so they match the id of the div's

Then you can use:

```
$("select").on("change", function() {
  $('[id^=season]').hide();  // This will hide all element that has an id starting with season
  $('#' + $(this).val()).show();  // example '#season1'
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#season1').show();
  $('#season2').hide();

  $("select").on("change", function() {
    $('[id^=season]').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Season:</h4>
<select>
  <option value="season1">Winter 2017</option>
  <option value="season2">Summer 2017</option>
</select>
<div id="season2">
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>GP</th>
        <th>G</th>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>Pnts</th>
        <th>PiM</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="season1">
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>GP</th>
        <th>G</th>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>Pnts</th>
        <th>PiM</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Brad</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very much Carsten, I appreciate it!

Comment: @KyleSchmelzer no problem, happy to help